# Why doesn't an array access expression of a null array reference throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, language-specifications

Consider the following code:

```
int[] r = null;
r[0] = 1 % 0;
```

I would have expected this to throw a `NullPointerException`: according to [JLS Sec 15.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1):

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

`=` is a binary operator (shown in [JLS Sec 15.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2) - JLS Sec 15.26 describes assignment operators), and fully-evaluating the left-hand operand will result in a `NullPointerException`. However, an `ArithmeticException` is thrown, indicating that the right-hand operand is evaluated before the left-hand operand is fully evaluated.

Why?

Answer (score 5):

The specification of [the simple assignment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1) describes this behavior:

> ...
>
> If the left-hand operand is an array access expression (§15.10.3), possibly enclosed in one or more pairs of parentheses, then:
>
> - First, the array reference subexpression of the left-hand operand array access expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason; the index subexpression (of the left-hand operand array access expression) and the right-hand operand are not evaluated and no assignment occurs.

This completes normally.

> - Otherwise, the index subexpression of the left-hand operand array access expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and the right-hand operand is not evaluated and no assignment occurs.

This completes normally.

> - Otherwise, the right-hand operand is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no assignment occurs.

This completes abruptly, with `ArithmeticException`.

> - Otherwise, if the value of the array reference subexpression is null, then no assignment occurs and a NullPointerException is thrown.

This is never executed.

So, it appears that there is inconsistency - or over-simplification, at least - in the quote from Sec 15.7.1.

---

Interestingly, the same behavior is not observed for the compound assignment operators, e.g.

```
int[] arr = null;
arr[0] += 1 % 0;
```

*does* yield a `NullPointerException`.

[JLS Sec 15.26.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) describes this. It's perhaps less surprising, though, because:

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

In other words, this code is (roughly) equivalent to:

```
arr[0] = arr[0] + 1 % 0;
```

so the `NullPointerException` occurs in evaluating the *right hand* operand of the simple assignment.