# Java Arithmetic expression

Tags: java, operators

The following expression evaluates to 14.

```
    int a=4;
    int b=6;
    int c=1;
    int ans= ++c + b % a - (c - b * c);
    System.out.print(ans);
```

This is how i calculate this

```
    1. (c - b * c) // since bracket has highest preference
    ans : -5
    2. ++c //since unary operator has next highest preference
    ans : 2
    3. b%a // % has higher preference than + and -
    ans : 2
```

Therefore, 2 + 2 - (-5) = 9

As you can see I'm getting 9 as the value. Not sure what's wrong in my way of calculation (pretty sure I'm gonna end up looking stupid)

Edit : I refered to the below link for precedence and association.
https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Can someone explain the difference between level 16 and level 13 parentheses? I thought level 13 parentheses is used only for typecasting. That is why i considered level 16 parenthesis for evaluating the expression.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373976/precedence-of-and-operators-in-java check this one and the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Evaluation order is not the same as precedence. [Java *always* evaluates left-to-right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7). Precedence then describes how the values are combined.

Comment: Specifically this is the same as doing `int ans = 2 + 6 % 4 - (2 - 6 * 2);` if you want to compare to the real math equation.

Comment: Ignore my now deleted comment. `++` is indeed executed first, even though parenthesis have a [higher operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/). See @AndyTurner's comment and answer for clarification on the left-to-right evaluation.

Answer (score 5):

Evaluation order is not the same as precedence. [Java *always* evaluates left-to-right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) (with a minor caveat around [array accesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854455/why-doesnt-an-array-access-expression-of-a-null-array-reference-throw-a-nullpoi)).

Effectively, you are evaluating the following expression, because the very first thing that happens is the pre-increment of `c`:

```
2 + 6 % 4 - (2 - 6 * 2)
```

Precedence then describes how the values are combined.

Comment: @T.Lucas so, how do you think `++c * ++c` would be evaluated?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `pre-increment` operator on c. So, after applying `increment` on `c` the value of `c` will be `2`. Now :

`(c - b * c)` will be evaluated to  `(2 - 6 * 2)= -10`

So, the final expression will be `2 + 2 - (-10) = 14`